# Reply-To address ignored when replying

Tags: email, email-client

I'm using a 'noreply' email address to send out transactional emails from my e-commerce platform. A 'Reply-To' address is used so that customers can reply directly to sellers.

This works as expected in most cases however I see a few cases in which customers' replies are sent to the From address rather than to the Reply-To address. (To be exact, I can't be sure whether those emails are /only/ sent to the Reply-To address or /also/ sent to the Reply-To address).

Replies are coming from @gmail.com accounts, @libero.it, etc, so it's not a provider-specific issue.

Using my own personal @gmail.com email, I can't replicate this as Gmail correctly honors the Reply-To address.

My searches online have been fruitless and the few cases I have do not come with a X-Mailer header so I can't pinpoint this to specific email clients.

How would I go about debugging this?

Comment: I believe Outlook wantonly ignores `Reply-To:`. The 'referred solution would be for nobody to use Outlook, but I don't think it's realistic - many Outlook users simply don't know what a functional email client looks like.